# picker in android with dynamic data. but it giving me a error " cannot read property of null"

Tags: react-native

i am trying to render a picker with dynamic data from api. but it is giving error

```
    <Picker style={styles.pickerStyleClass}
                                           enabled={true} mode="dropdown"
                                           selectedValue={(this.state.selectedWeight) || "Status"} prompt="Transaction Type"
                                           onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.PickerDataSelection(itemIndex, itemValue)}
                                           itemStyle={{ color: Colors.textColor }}>
                                           {stockQty.map((data) => { <Picker.Item label={data} value={data} /> })}

                                       </Picker>

let stockQty = ["Test1","Test2"];
```

Comment: Hi! Your code looks ok, can you post all component?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing missing here that causes this error is `return` so replace the Picker.Item line to

```
{stockQty.map((data) => { return <Picker.Item label={data} value={data} /> })}
```

as nothing was being returned from the function and Picker is made in a way that you can't return anything other than Picker.Item with the required props. Even the following line gives the same error.

```
{ this.state.someCheck && <Picker.Item label='some' value='value' /> }
```

and `key` should also be added as prop in Picker.Item.